# Convert Loop problem to Recursive Solution in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I've written the following method (working perfectly fine) which takes a list and returns a list of lists containing the
elements, so that the first list contains half of list’s elements, the next contains half of the remaining elements, and so on. For example,

```
repHalve(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15))
```

Returning:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), List(9, 10, 11, 12), List(13, 14), List(15))
```

The question is I'm new to Scala and wanted to convert this method to recursive approach. Please let me know how should I convert this. I know the base case could be the same as the condition inside while loop but still unable to figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
def repHalve(list:List[Any]){

    var local_list:List[Any] = list
    var list_of_lists:List[Any] = List.empty

    while(local_list.length>1){
      val sub = local_list.slice(0, (local_list.length/2)+1)
      list_of_lists  ++= List(sub)
      local_list = local_list.slice(local_list.length/2+1, local_list.length)
    }

    list_of_lists ++= List(List(list.last))
    println(list_of_lists)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider analogous solution to Luis' but using `splitAt`

```
def repHalve(l: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
  def half(i: Int): Int = if ((i % 2) == 0) i / 2 else (i + 1) / 2

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[Int], size: Int, acc: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = l match {
    case x :: Nil => (List(x) :: acc).reverse
    case _ =>
      val (left, right) = l.splitAt(half(size))
      loop(right, right.size, left :: acc)
  }
  loop(l, l.size, Nil)
}
```

jmh benchmark using `(1 to 200).toList` as input indicates Luis' solution is faster

```
[info] So60178352._luis   thrpt    5  666357.490 ± 165323.129  ops/s
[info] So60178352._mario  thrpt    5  591174.959 ± 118097.426  ops/s
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely *tail-recursive* implementation.
Let me know if you have any questions.

```
def repHalve[T](list: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
  def half(i: Int): Int = 
    if ((i % 2) == 0) i / 2 else (i + 1) / 2

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T], targetLength: Int, acc: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil => acc.reverse

      case list =>
        @annotation.tailrec
        def innerLoop(remaining: List[T], currentLength: Int, acc: List[T]): (List[T], List[T]) =
          remaining match {
            case x :: xs =>
              if (currentLength != targetLength)
                innerLoop(remaining = xs, currentLength + 1, x :: acc)
              else
                (x :: xs, acc.reverse)
            case Nil =>
              (Nil, acc.reverse)
          }

        val (remaining, newList) = innerLoop(remaining = list, currentLength = 0, acc = List.empty)
        loop(remaining, half(targetLength), newList :: acc)
    }

  loop(remaining = list, targetLength = half(list.length), acc = List.empty)
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
repHalve((1 to 20).toList)
// res: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), List(11, 12, 13, 14, 15), List(16, 17, 18), List(19, 20))
```